# Stochastic integration by parts

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

My professor asserts
[image]

However, Oksendal asserts in his textbook:
$X_{t} Y_{t}-X_{0} Y_{0}=\int_{0}^{t} X_{s} d Y_{s}+\int_{0}^{t} Y_{s} d X_{s}+\int_{0}^{t}dXdY$

These are not equivalent - consider $e^{t/2}W_{t}$ for standard brownian motion $W_{t}$ - the "$g_{t}dW_{t}$" term for $e^{t/2}$ is such that $g_{t}=0$.

Is my professor's version incorrect?

Comment: If one thinks of $\, d X \,d Y$ to mean $d \langle X, Y\rangle$ then all the integration by parts formulae seem to be consistent with each other:  $$\,d \langle X, Y \rangle_t = b_tg_t \,d \langle W_1, W_2\rangle_t= \begin{cases} 0 , \text{ if } W_1 \text{ and } W_2 \text{ are independent} \\ b_tg_t \,d t , \text{ if   } W_1 = W_2 =W\end{cases}.$$ Your counterexample is unclear to me.

Comment: that is, $de^{t/2}=(1/2)e^{t/2}dt + 0dW_{t}$. Further, $dXdY$ is apparently literally just the product of the two differentials.

Comment: $\,d X \,d Y $ can be interpreted as a product of differentials, but these products must also follow the formal rules set down in Oksendal's book, cf. theorem 4.1.2 (p. 44). According to these rules  $\, dX_t \, d Y_t = b_tg_t \,d t$ when $W_1=W_2 = W$.

In your example, the second formula (3.3.28), gives you $$ e^{t/2} W_t - e^{0/2}W_0 =  \int_0^t W_s \,d (e^{s/2}) + \int_0^t e^{s/2} \,d W_s$$ because $b_s =0, g_s=1$, while the third formula also gives you the same thing, because $\,d s \cdot \,d W_s =0$ according to the rules mentioned above. So there is no contradiction.

Comment: @Sayantan I see, thank you for pointing this out